# Why $1...$9 Properties (RegExp) doesnt work with IE10?

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-10

I have a old script that it used to work with IE, but I dont know why it doesnt work only with IE10, anyone has some clue about it?

```
String.Format = function (a) {
    var b = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return a.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function () { return b[RegExp.$1] });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FDeprecated_Features#RegExp_Properties), the `RegExp.$n` properties are deprecated.

Try this instead:

```
return a.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match) { 
    // match will include the {} so we strip all non-digits
    return b[match.replace(/\D/g, '')];
});
```

Or use the first parenthesized match to avoid the extra `replace` call:

```
return a.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, p1) { 
    return b[p1];
});
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sjxkD/)

Comment: Yah, thanks! I'm to lazy to figure it out by myself.  Just one observation, we have to use the second paramter sent to action function for this script works.

Comment: @Cleiton im not sure what you mean by second parameter to action function. see my working example for a demonstration.

Comment: The function used by "replace" regex function. lol. i'm sorry i'm not a good english speaker. this is what i meant http://jsfiddle.net/sjxkD/1/. i wrote that comment before see your last modifications. anyway thanks very much!

Comment: @Cleiton yes it is probably better to use the second parameter to avoid any unneccesary replace calls.

Answer (score 1):

Those properties are deprecated. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Properties.